# Route to flask and vue containers with traefik

Tags: docker, docker-compose, traefik

I am attempting to adapt [this](https://github.com/tiangolo/full-stack-fastapi-postgresql) to use traefik v2, but I am failing miseably. All the services can talk to eachother and are working but I cannot get the routes to work for dev env. I dont understand why.

docker-compose.dev.command.yml:

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  proxy:
    command:
      - "--log.level=DEBUG"
      - "--api.insecure=true"
      - "--providers.docker.endpoint=unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
      - "--providers.docker.swarmMode=false"
      - "--providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false"
      - "--entrypoints.web.address=:80"
      - "--entrypoints.traefik.address=:8080"

  # backend:
  #   command: bash -c "while true; do sleep 1; done"  # Infinite loop to keep container live doing nothing

  backend:
    command: /start-reload.sh
```

docker-compose.dev.labels.yml:

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  proxy:
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.rule=Host(`localhost`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.rule=PathPrefix(`/dashboard/`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.entrypoints=traefik"

  backend:
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.backend.entrypoints=web"
      - "traefik.http.routers.backend.rule=Host(`localhost`) && PathPrefix(`/redoc`) || PathPrefix(`/api`) || PathPrefix(`/docs`)"

  frontend:
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.frontend.entrypoints=web"
      - "traefik.http.routers.frontend.rule=Host(`localhost`) && PathPrefix(`/`)"
```

docker-compose.dev.networks.yml:

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  backend:
    networks:
      default:
        aliases:
          - ${DOMAIN}
```

I tried just about anything I can think of but I just cant get this to work. If i check the traefik dashboard, the routers are refering to the correct services at the correct IP:s, and I can try the manually to ensure they are working, but the routes just wont work.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Use spa-to-http to serve your Vue container, it is super-simple: Just create a Dockerfile in your frontend folder with next content:

```
FROM node:16-alpine as builder
WORKDIR /code/
ADD package-lock.json .
ADD package.json .
RUN npm ci
ADD . .
RUN npm run build

FROM devforth/spa-to-http:latest
COPY --from=builder /code/dist/ .
```

To route traefik in compose use:

```
myapp:     
   build: "frontend" # name of the folder where Dockerfile is located 
   labels:
     - "traefik.enable=true"
     - "traefik.http.routers.myapp.rule=Host(`myapp.localhost`)"       - 
     - "traefik.http.services.myapp.loadbalancer.server.port=8080" # route traffic t0 port 8080
```

If you need more info you can read my [Detailed step-by-step guide to serve Vue.js app using Traefik and spa-to-http](https://devforth.io/blog/zero-configuration-spa-serving-in-docker-with-traefik-and-spa-to-http/)

Also, here is a GitHub repository: [spa-to-http page on GitHub](https://github.com/devforth/spa-to-http).

Disclosure: I am a CEO of company which created spa-to-http for own need. We open-sourced it and licensed with MIT, so you can use it for any commercial projects

Answer (score 0):

you are missing the service label for your definitions, you need at least the following labels on your backend services

```
        - traefik.enable=true
        - traefik.http.routers.backend.entrypoints=web
        - traefik.http.services.backend.loadbalancer.server.port=${rplace with service port}
        - traefik.http.routers.backend.rule=Host(`localhost`) && PathPrefix(`/redoc`) || PathPrefix(`/api`) || PathPrefix(`/docs`)
        - traefik.http.routers.backend.service=backend
        - traefik.docker.network=traefik
```

same for the reset of the services, you can read more about this [here](https://medium.com/better-programming/traefik-2-1-as-a-reverse-proxy-c9e274da0a32)

Comment: All the services including traefik are using a default network that is created when you run docker-compose up. I tried your solution but it still does not work. (Its not running in swarm mode)

Comment: you are missing this line `traefik.http.services.backend.loadbalancer.server.port` is it the most important one